# Find better algorithm for partial sorting problem

Tags: algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

Given an array A[1..n] and an integer k with k ≪ n, the partial sort problem is to return the k smallest numbers in order from the given n numbers. What is an efficient algorithm for the partial sort problem. Is there any other way which is better than selection algorithm???

Comment: could you provide more information about your solution you come with? also I would suggest to build min heap and take the first kth elements which gives you O(n + k*logn)

Comment: I would also use a min heap. For instance, python even has a function `nsmallest` in the `heapq` module which does exactly what you're asking and uses a min heap. An alternative is to use [quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) then sort the first k elements, which gives expected runtime O(n + k log(k)), worst-case runtime O(n² + k log(k)).

Comment: See also: [Algorithm notes for nlargest() and nsmallest()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/heapq.py#L397) and [Compare algorithms for heapq.smallest (Python recipe)](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577573-compare-algorithms-for-heapqsmallest/)

Comment: You can use the divide and conquer median finding algorithm to find the k-smallest number in the array (O(n)), then going threw the array again and take all the numbers that are smaller than the k-smallest number (O(n)) and finally sorting the new array (O(klog(k))). at last: O(n + klog(k))

Comment: @stef: You use a maxheap to find the n smallest (and so does `nsmallest`: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/heapq.py#L493). It's a maxheap because you need to know which is the largest of the current n smallest values, so as to decide whether to insert a newly encountered value, which is inserted if it's less than the current max.